# Server 2012 R2 VDI number of standby VMs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, remote-desktop-services, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, vdi

We are currently testing a Windows 10 VDI deployment built on server 2012 R2 remote desktop services.

In a pooled VDI deployment, it appears that the deployment actively keeps 2 VMs running ready for connection by end users, and upon a user login, it powers on another one to ensure there are always 2 VMs ready.

I am curious if there is a way to define the number of active standby VMs to accommodate for login storms? We would much rather have this number set to something like 10, so that it can better deal with multiple users connecting at once.

I suspect but cannot test, that when 3 users attempt to login at the same time, 2 will be connected to the running VMs, but the third will have to wait longer for another VM to be resumed from a saved state. I get the feeling this will result in a worse login experience for this user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set-RDVirtualDesktopIdleCount
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj215508(v=wps.630).aspx